# How to track down a variable with an address in C#

Tags: c#, pinvoke, dllimport

I am currently passing a large number of arrays into a fortran subroutine through the use of [DLLImport].  Everything outwardly looks like correct except I am getting the following [image]exception about every other time I run the process.

It is my understanding that this means I have corrupted the memory somewhere in un-managed code.

How can I figure out which variable in c# is at the address that is in the error message so I can start to narrow down where I corrupting the memory?  i.e. what c# object is located @ 0x739c1263 ?

Comment: There is no C# object located at 0x739c1263, that message means there was a error in the fortran code with a fortran object.

Comment: The fortran code runs to completion, and most of the objects are instantiated in c# and passed to fortran.

Comment: It's possible that your P/Invoke declarations are incorrect, and things are being corrupted on the stack when values are marshaled to or from the Fortran library.

Comment: You need to show your C method signatures and the P/Invoke you used with them

Comment: Unfortunately they are proprietary and I can't share the signatures, I know it is silly but those are the constraints I am working with.  I have checked them and my fortran process is running and exiting, it is just that the c# program crashes some random time after the process has been run.  Hence the reason I am trying to track down what object is at the specific spot in memory.

Comment: Have you tried to pin the variables in C# and get their address with `ToIntPtr`?

Answer (score 0):

Use DebugDiag.

You can take a memory snapshot and navigate through your variables.

Comment: As this isn't an answer but a suggestion, it'd better serve as a comment on the OP.

Comment: Can you link to or provide instructions on how to use debugdiag?

Comment: Check here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff420662.aspx
Also WinDbg http://windbg.info/doc/1-common-cmds.html